# The images after rendering the animation are corrupted

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Recently, after I try to render an animation, I obtain strange white images with black block stripes. It does it it in both image sequences and video output. I've already had normal animations with this project but now it is the only result I obtain.

If someone have a solution to solve this problem, it would be welcomed.

An example of the results I have : [image: Here is the image sequences I had after rendering.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed : I had another strip in the sequencer from a previous render which caused the interferences.